# Django - Generic One-to-One Relation

Tags: django, generics, django-models, one-to-one, generic-foreign-key

I have a website with different kinds of activities:

- Lessons ;
- Exercises ;
- Quizzes.

So far, each type of activity corresponds to a specific Model and a table in the database. I would like to create an ordered path through these activities. For instance:

- Lesson 1
- then Exercise 1
- then Lesson 2
- then Quizz 1
- etc.

I am considering to create a model named **Activity** that would store the following data:

- A number: the number of the activity in the path ;
- A One-To-One relationship to one given activity (lesson, exercise, quizz etc.).

(1) I have seen that Django offers a GenericForeignKey to handle many-to-one relationship  to different kinds of models, like many comments associated to a single lesson or a single exercise. Is there something similar for Generic OneToOne relationship?

(2) I would like to track the progress of my users. To do so, I am considering having a many-to-many relationship called "done_activities" built in my User model and linked to my Activity model. Do you think this is an efficient way of approaching the problem ?

Comment: This might be something to look at: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/13/how-to-use-generic-relations.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you would need or want self-referential fields in this case.  Consider the following structure as an example.  I do not propose this 'in stone' as THE solution, but more to spur your own ideas about the solution you need.  Please note that I'm leaving out `__str__` methods and such for brevity:

```
ACTIVITY_TYPE = ['Lesson', 'Exercise', 'Quiz']

class Activity(models.Model):
    activity_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    activity_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=ACTIVITY_TYPE, blank=True, db_index=True)
    activity_desc = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True) #description of the lesson, exercise, or quiz

class Program(models.Model):
    program_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, db_index=True)
    description  = models.Charfield(max_length=200, blank=True)

class ProgramActivity(models.Model):
    program     = models.ForeignKey(Program, on_delete=models.CASCADE, your args etc...)
    activity     = models.ForeignKey(Activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE, your args here etc...)
    path_order  = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField() # stores a number for the order in the program path

class UserProgram(models.Model):
    student    = models.ForeignKey(User, etc...) # FK to the user
    program    = models.ForeignKey(Program, etc...) # connects users to programs
    progress   = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2) # stores percentage of program completed (for example)
```

In this schema scenario, the following are true:

1. `Activity`s are all tracked and stored together on a single table,
   organized by type, and each one can have its own description.
2. `Program`s are stored on their own model, and
   represent a named object that unites all their constituent activities.
3. `ProgramActivity` connects activities to specific programs, and
   allows you to set the order in the path for that activity *relative to the program*, and change it easily if you have to.  You can easily query `activities = ProgramActivity.objects.filter(program=some_program).order_by('path_order')` and get a very usable list of a Program's activities.
4. Finally the `UserProgram` model records a User's "enrollments" and
   progress in each, in this example, by percentage of the program completed.

This is just one possible approach.  You may, for example, want to create an activity type table instead of a list dropdown, which may be a more robust way of managing activities over time.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion ! I understand that you suggest to build a general Activity model embracing all the different kinds of activities in one table. Yet, what if my different kinds of activities store very different data ? For instance, there could be a lesson storing a textual content vs. a video extract storing a video URL, explanations and so on. If I understand correctly, I would have a big model definition with lots of nullable fields depending on the type of activity.

Comment: You're welcome!  To answer your question about the media types:  Ask yourself the following: will every activity only ever have ONE of the following: text, files, pictures, or URLs?  Could an activity have a document AND a video?  What about their number?  Maybe an activity has three videos?   What I'm saying is that you may need separate models for these things, foreign keyed to the `Activity` model.  Something like `ActivityMedia`, `ActivityFile`, `ActivityURL`, and so on.  That way you can add as many of those things as you need, or even mark some as "active" with a boolean, for example.